# Run terminal command before tests - Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, fakes3

I'm testing an S3 connection with fakeS3 and it works perfectly. The only downside is I have to run the fake S3 server every time before I run my tests or the S3 test will break obviously.

I want to figure out a way to run this command before my test run:

`fakes3 -r ~/.s3bucket -p 4567`

This will in theory start the Sinatra server so that the S3 test will pass but I don't need to start a separate server each time.

I've tried this and it didn't work for good reason:

#### MIX.exs

```
 test: ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "fakes3 -r ~/.s3bucket -p 4567", "test"]
```

That doesn't work because it's not a mix task.

I'm also probably thinking of this the wrong way. How can I have the command run before my tests and is this the right way to think about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`ExUnit.Callbacks.setup_all/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html#setup_all/1):

```rb
def fakes3(_context) do
  System.cmd("fakes3", ~w|-r ~/.s3bucket -p 4567|)
  :ok
end

setup_all :fakes3
```

The above is to be put into the case you use to test S3.

---

BTW, this could be done with `mix` as well. It has [`run`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Run.html#content) task that accepts either the script to run or an expression to eval as an argument:

```rb
test: [ 
  "ecto.create --quiet",
  "ecto.migrate",
  ~S[run -e "System.cmd(~s|fakes3|, ~w|-r ~/.s3bucket -p 4567|)"],
  "test"
]
```

Comment: Sorry to ask you to spell this out but where do I put the fakes3 function?

Comment: Into the case you use to test S3, like `test/fakes3_test.exs`, anywhere inside the module.

Comment: What is  `~S` in it ? And also the smaller `~s`?